# Can resharper jump to the file that contains the unit tests?

Tags: c#, resharper

Is it possible to somehow link or use some convention so I can jump between my unit tests for a given class?

Also, creating short cuts for jumping between the interface, the implementations?

(keyboard shortcuts)

Example:

IUserService
UserService
UserServiceTests

It would be great if I can somehow link these together so I can jump to any of these files while in any one of them currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Is it possible to somehow link or use some convention so I can jump between my unit tests for a given class?

To jump between unit tests for a given class, launch ReSharper's **Find Usages** on the class name, and as soon as you have results in the **Find Results** tool window, group them in a way that helps focus on usages in a particular part of your code base - for example, by project and type. This will let detect usages in your test project. From there, you can quickly jump from **Find Results** to actual usages in code. As an alternative, you can use ReSharper's **Go to Usages of Symbol** that works in a similar way but displays search results in a pop-up menu instead of flushing them to **Find Results**.

If your test classes contain metadata showing which business logic they're covering, this would help even better in differentiating the usages you need. For example, if you're using MSpec, test classes are marked with the *Subject* attribute: `[Subject(typeof (MyCoveredClass))]` This is handy because usages within this attribute are very visible, and navigating to them leads you directly to declarations of your test classes:
[image: Find MSpec test classes that cover a particular class]

With NUnit and MSTest, this is a bit more complicated as their attributes take strings as parameters, like this: `[TestProperty("TestKind", "MyCoveredClass")]`. In order to find such a usage of `MyCoveredClass`, you'll have to use ReSharper's **Find Usages Advanced** and turn on the **Textual occurrences** option.

> > Also, creating short cuts for jumping between the interface, the implementations?

As to jumping within an inheritance chain, ReSharper provides multiple options to do that, including **Type Hierarchy** (ReSharper > Inspect > Type Hierarchy) and **Go to Implementation** (ReSharper > Navigate > Go to Implementation):

[image: Navigating throughout inheritance chains with Go to Implementation and/or Type Hierarchy]

Answer (score 7):

I just implemented that feature in [TestLinker](https://github.com/matkoch/TestLinker), which is a ReSharper 2016.1 extension. It is available to install from the ReSharper Gallery.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 3):

As has already been mentioned you can do this using the [TestCop ReSharper](https://github.com/testcop/Resharper.TestCop) plugin ([gallery link](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/Resharper.TestCop.R9/)).

It ties the class under test to the test fixture by using regular expressions to identify class names and namespaces. You can customise these to fit your needs, but I found there to be a fair amount of trial and error to get this right on existing code.

Once it's all set up you can go back and forth with a keyboard shortcut. It can also do things like create the TestFixture or the class for you.

Comment: TestCop doesn't seem to be available anymore. Doesn't appear in the Resharper 10 list of extensions. Also last release was 2015-07-14.

Comment: I've updated the gallery link to point at the latest version of TestCop. At the time of writing it supports ReSharper 2016.3 and was updated on 2017-01-01.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper doesn't have a specific Goto Test/Code feature other than navigating through the list of usages.

However, [TestDriven.NET has this feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2010/06/09/testdriven-net-3-0-all-systems-go.aspx) which uses naming conventions to find the Test/Code peer such that you can flip back and forth.

> Also, creating short cuts for jumping between the interface, the
>   implementations?

ReSharper has this feature. Using the Visual Studio scheme:

- Alt + Home navigates to the class' base, in case there are more than one a context menu will list them
- Alt + End navigates down the inheritance hierarchy and behaves like Alt + Home

Ctrl + U and Ctrl + Alt + B respectively is the equivalent for the ReSharper 2.x / IDEA scheme.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think this is going to be possible with just resharper.  as far as resharper is concerned, your unit test is just another usage of UserService.

also, all of the different unit testing frameworks specify things differently, so it'd be tough to know.  for instance, doing bdd would yield test class names almost entirely unrelated to the class(es) being tested.

you might be able to write an extension to do this, maybe using attributes or something?  not sure.

Comment: I see, I didn't know you could extend resharper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ReSharper Extension [TestCop](https://testcop.codeplex.com/)

This plugin is designed for use with mstest & nunit but should work with any other unittest framework that requires you to assign a test Attribute.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

With ReSharper and NUnit, to jump from test to subject, you can use the `TestOf` property of the `TestFixture` attribute. Just Ctrl + Click on `MyClass` in the test file:

```
[TestFixture(TestOf = typeof(MyClass))]
public class MyClassTest
```

To jump from subject to test, use the ReSharper **Find usage** command.